# help: looking for a generic (and elegant) array (variable) map syntax to keep stuff

Tags: macros, options

My apologies if this has been discussed elsewhere, but if it was I couldn't find it.

I am the author of a template for academic thesis for my university, but I'm definitely not a TeX expert.  In this template I make extensive use of configuration file(s) that use an ad-hoc (self) defined array map. E.g.:

```
\arraymay{cover}
\cover{phd}={phd_cover_file.pdf}
\cover{msg}={msc_cover_file.pdf}
\arraymap{margin}
\margin{cover,left}={5cm}
\margin{cover,right}={5cm}
\margin{cover,top}={4cm}
\margin{cover,bottom}={4cm}
\margin{main,left}={3cm}
\margin{main,right}={3cm}
\margin{main,top}={2cm}
\margin{main,bottom}={2cm}
```

Commas in keys are used for visual effect and considered as a normal character, i.e., in “`\margin{cover,bottom}={2cm}`” the key is “`cover,bottom`”.

I can later access the values as in:

```
\def\manuscripttype{phd}
The cover file is ``\thecover[\manuscripttype]'' and the margins for the cover are ``\themargin[cover,left], \themargin[cover,right], \themargin[cover,top], and \themargin[cover,bottom].''
```

will produce

```
The cover file is “phd_cover_file.pdf” and the margins for the cover are “3cm, 3cm, 2cm, and 2cm.”
```

Is there any other (solid) package implementing this functionality?  If not, is there some solid way to implement it (maybe based in one of the KV packages)?  Thanks.

Comment: I'd much prefer something like `\margin{cover/left=5cm,cover/right=5cm,...}`

Comment: @egreg, I agree with you and I was precisely looking at pgfkeys. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `pgfkeys`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  lourenco/.cd,
  cover/phd/.initial={},
  cover/msc/.initial={},
  margin/cover/left/.initial=0pt,
  margin/cover/right/.initial=0pt,
  margin/cover/top/.initial=0pt,
  margin/cover/bottom/.initial=0pt,
  margin/main/left/.initial=0pt,
  margin/main/right/.initial=0pt,
  margin/main/top/.initial=0pt,
  margin/main/bottom/.initial=0pt,
}

\newcommand{\setlourenco}[1]{\pgfkeys{lourenco/.cd,#1}}
\newcommand{\thecover}[1]{%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/lourenco/cover/#1}%
}
\newcommand{\themargin}[1]{%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/lourenco/margin/#1}%
}

%% settings
\setlourenco{
  cover/phd=phd-cover-file.pdf,
  cover/msc=msc-cover-file.pdf,
  margin/cover/left=5cm,
  margin/cover/right=5cm,
  margin/cover/top=4cm,
  margin/cover/bottom=4cm,
  margin/main/left=3cm,
  margin/main/right=3cm,
  margin/main/top=2cm,
  margin/main/bottom=2cm,
}

\def\manuscripttype{phd}

\begin{document}

The cover file is ``\thecover{\manuscripttype}'' and the margins 
for the cover are ``\themargin{cover/left}, \themargin{cover/right},
\themargin{cover/top}, and \themargin{cover/bottom}.''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am going to nit-pick as it has Very Very frequently caused editorial problems and measurement errors when numbers are butted up hard agains units and whilst it may be common practice in many non American organisations the old rule was best USE   SPACE   FOR  CLARITY see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/punctuation-with-units in dim light is that 4c m or 40 m

Comment: @KJO Here the purpose is to show how to access the values, not to pretty print them. The OP wants to use `\themargin{cover/top}` for passing the value to `geometry` or for doing a direct assignment to a parameter.

Comment: I am worried it is for a global "template" unless its target is Chicago style I suggest it could be made universally acceptable.